# What is the effect of extern "C" in C++?

Tags: c++, c, linkage, name-mangling, extern-c

What exactly does putting `extern "C"` into C++ code do?

For example:

```
extern "C" {
   void foo();
}
```

Comment: I'd like to introduce you this article: [http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf) It tells you much more about calling convention and the difference between compilers.

Answer (score 1999, accepted):

`extern "C"` makes a function-name in C++ have C linkage (compiler does not mangle the name) so that client C code can link to (use) your function using a C compatible header file that contains just the declaration of your function. Your function definition is contained in a binary format (that was compiled by your C++ compiler) that the client C linker will then link to using the C name.

Since C++ has overloading of function names and C does not, the C++ compiler cannot just use the function name as a unique id to link to, so it mangles the name by adding information about the arguments.  A C compiler does not need to mangle the name since you can not overload function names in C.  When you state that a function has `extern "C"` linkage in C++, the C++ compiler does not add argument/parameter type information to the name used for linkage.

Just so you know, you can specify `extern "C"` linkage to each individual declaration/definition explicitly or use a block to group a sequence of declarations/definitions to have a certain linkage:

```
extern "C" void foo(int);
extern "C"
{
   void g(char);
   int i;
}
```

If you care about the technicalities, they are listed in section 7.5 of the C++03 standard, here is a brief summary (with emphasis on `extern "C"`):

- `extern "C"` is a linkage-specification
- Every compiler is *required* to provide "C" linkage
- A linkage specification shall occur only in namespace scope
- <strike>All function types, function names and variable names have a language linkage</strike>  **[See Richard's Comment:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/in-c-source-what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c#comment20842899_1041880)** Only function names and variable names with external linkage have a language linkage
- Two function types with distinct language linkages are distinct types even if otherwise identical
- Linkage specs nest, inner one determines the final linkage
- `extern "C"` is ignored for class members
- At most one function with a particular name can have "C" linkage (regardless of namespace)
- <strike>`extern "C"` forces a function to have external linkage (cannot make it static)</strike>   **[See Richard's comment:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c-in-c?rq=1#comment20842893_1041880)**    `static` inside `extern "C"` is valid; an entity so declared has internal linkage, and so does not have a language linkage
- Linkage from C++ to objects defined in other languages and to objects defined in C++ from other languages is implementation-defined and language-dependent. Only where the object layout strategies of two language implementations are similar enough can such linkage be achieved

Comment: This appears to be under-the-hood ... is there any functional reason why I would put 'extern "C"' in front of a function (other than to call it from a separate C program)?

Comment: C compiler does not use mangling which c++'s does. So if you want call a c interface from a c++ program, you have to clearly declared that the c interface as "extern c".

Comment: @Litherum - if you do not intend your code to be linked-to by a different C++ compiler or any C compiler or some dynamic language (ruby, python etc) for which you are developing an extension - you don't need extern "C". It buys you nothing.

Comment: @Faisal: do not try to link code built with different C++ compilers, even if the cross-references are all 'extern "C"'.  There are often differences between the layouts of classes, or the mechanisms used to handle exceptions, or the mechanisms used to ensure variables are initialized before use, or other such differences, plus you might need two separate C++ run-time support libraries (one for each compiler).

Comment: @Leffler - thanks, you make good points.  I did not mean to encourage using different C++ compilers by using extern "C".  Rather, I was hoping to suggest that if you are not writing something that would need to be linked to by another C++ compiler, you probably don't need extern "C".

Comment: No mention of calling convention?  No mention that the Standard requires using `extern "C"` modifiers on functions pointers in order to call C linkage functions (although in practice many implementations don't care)?

Comment: 'extern "C" forces a function to have external linkage (cannot make it static)' is incorrect. 'static' inside 'extern "C"' is valid; an entity so declared has internal linkage, and so does not have a language linkage.

Comment: Richard's actually wrong.  Language linkage affects calling convention, the Standard doesn't say whether it's possible to call an `extern "C"` function using a function pointer that isn't specifically declared as pointing to an `extern "C"` type.  Function types DO have language linkage.  That said, I've never seen an implementation which takes advantage of the flexibility with the Standard allows in this area.

Comment: Note that `extern "C" { int i; }` is a definition.  This may not be what you intended, next to the non-definition of `void g(char);`.  To make it a non-definition, you would need `extern "C" { extern int i; }`.  On the other hand, the one-declaration syntax without braces does make the declaration a non-definition: `extern "C" int i;` is the same as `extern "C" { extern int i; }`

Comment: Do I have to do this for just the included header files, or around every function that uses the functions contained in those headers, or a mixture of both?

Comment: Another way to put this is that `extern "C"` tells the compiler that those symbols will be found in object files that conform to the C ABI (for that compiler, of course) , as opposed to the C++ ABI.

Comment: How can one specify C++ linkage?

Comment: @FUZxxl, `extern "C++"`, unsurprisingly.

Comment: What if I wrap a C++ class defination in extern "C" { ... } ? Especially when: 1. this class has functions with the same name; 2. this class has functions that return C++ class object ? If compiler does not mangle these function names, how would it be linked properly?

Comment: @godspeed1024 Wrapping a class with extern "C" will get you a compiler error. But even if it didn't, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025345/extern-c-can-not-be-used-at-class-level) points out that C language linkage is ignored for member functions.

Comment: if we use of `extern "C"` name mangling doesn't occur because c has not name mangling, so `extern "C"` cause keep declaration with definition names (because if not using of `extern "C"` it may change function or class declaration with name mangling)

Comment: I am a bit late here but what Leffler said about not linking to different c++ compiler code makes no sense to me. I do this all the time. Linking to SFML lib, lib I made in Visual studio to Code Blocks mingw. mingw32 to mingw64. Sounds ridiculous to me.

Answer (score 443):

Just wanted to add a bit of info, since I haven't seen it posted yet.

You'll very often see code in C headers like so:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// all of your legacy C code here

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

What this accomplishes is that it allows you to use that C header file with your C++ code, because the macro `__cplusplus` will be defined. But you can *also* still use it with your legacy C code, where the macro is *NOT* defined, so it won't see the uniquely C++ construct.

Although, I have also seen C++ code such as:

```
extern "C" {
#include "legacy_C_header.h"
}
```

which I imagine accomplishes much the same thing.

Not sure which way is better, but I have seen both.

Comment: There is a distinct difference. In case of the former, if you compile this file with normal gcc compiler it will generate an object where the function name is not mangled. If you then link C and C++ objects with the linker it will NOT find the functions. You will need to include those "legacy header" files with the extern keyword as in your second code block.

Comment: @Anne: The C++ compiler will look for unmangled names also, because it saw `extern "C"` in the header).  It works great, used this technique many times.

Comment: @Ben. I was referring to the sentence `Not sure which way is better, but I have seen both.`. There is a difference!

If you compile the first file with `gcc`, it didn't encounter the `extern "C"` phrase... So, if you don't use the second phrase in your C++ code you're still in trouble.

There is no difference if you use the same compiler for all files.

Comment: @Anne: That's not right, the first one is fine as well.  It's ignored by the C compiler, and has the same effect as the second in C++.  The compiler couldn't care less whether it encounters `extern "C"` before or after it includes the header.  By the time it reaches the compiler, it's just one long stream of preprocessed text anyway.

Comment: @Ben. Sure, as long the `g++` compiler hits the statement somewhere, you're fine. Perhaps I've worked with crappier g++ cross-compilers that didn't always figure out the entire tree of header files for me. :-)

Comment: @Anne, no, I think you've been affected by some other error in the source, because what you are describing is wrong. No version of `g++` got this wrong, for any target, at any time in the last 17 years at least. The whole point of the first example is that it doesn't matter whether you use a C or C++ compiler, no name mangling will be done for the names in the `extern "C"` block.

Comment: Good example of the first method are CPython header files: https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Include

Comment: "which one is better" - for sure, the first variant is better: It allows including the header directly, whithout any further requirements, both in C and C++ code. The second approach is a workaround for C headers the author forgot the C++ guards (no problem, though, if these are added afterwards, nested extern "C" declarations are accepteded...).

Comment: The second version is very-very cool. I was not aware of it. No need to pollute C code with __cplucplus, if entire C-code is required in C++. I'm writing a simulator/tester in C++ for legacy C-code. Including the C-headers this way works perfectly and C-code remains untouched.

Comment: Why says C is "legacy"?

Comment: @JL2210 should be obvious, C is the base language from which any number of modern languages were derived, including Java, C#, and of course, C++. It is the Grandfather of Programming Languages.

Comment: @UncaAlby "legacy" usually refers to "old and shouldn't be used anymore", not "the basis of many great programming languages".

Comment: @JL2210 yah, say that when **you** get old!! "1. adjective: denoting or relating to software or hardware that has been superseded but is difficult to replace because of its wide use." It just happens to *also* be a *fact* that it is the basis of many modern programming languages (not necessarily *great* mind you) You can't be the basis for modern languages without *also* being *old*.

Answer (score 426):

**Decompile a `g++` generated binary to see what is going on**

main.cpp

```
void f() {}
void g();

extern "C" {
    void ef() {}
    void eg();
}

/* Prevent g and eg from being optimized away. */
void h() { g(); eg(); }
```

Compile and disassemble the generated [ELF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294034/how-to-make-an-executable-elf-file-in-linux-using-a-hex-editor/30648229#30648229) output:

```
g++ -c -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o main.o main.cpp
readelf -s main.o
```

The output contains:

```
     8: 0000000000000000     7 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _Z1fv
     9: 0000000000000007     7 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 ef
    10: 000000000000000e    17 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 _Z1hv
    11: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
    12: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND _Z1gv
    13: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND eg
```

**Interpretation**

We see that:

- `ef` and `eg` were stored in symbols with the same name as in the code
- the other symbols were mangled. Let's unmangle them:

  ```
  $ c++filt _Z1fv
  f()
  $ c++filt _Z1hv
  h()
  $ c++filt _Z1gv
  g()
  ```

Conclusion: both of the following symbol types were *not* mangled:

- defined
- declared but undefined (`Ndx = UND`), to be provided at link or run time from another object file

So you will need `extern "C"` both when calling:

- C from C++: tell `g++` to expect unmangled symbols produced by `gcc`
- C++ from C: tell `g++` to generate unmangled symbols for `gcc` to use

**Things that do not work in extern C**

It becomes obvious that any C++ feature that requires name mangling will not work inside `extern C`:

```
extern "C" {
    // Overloading.
    // error: declaration of C function ‘void f(int)’ conflicts with
    void f();
    void f(int i);

    // Templates.
    // error: template with C linkage
    template <class C> void f(C i) { }
}
```

**Minimal runnable C from C++ example**

For the sake of completeness and for the newbs out there, see also: [How to use C source files in a C++ project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694605/how-to-use-c-source-files-in-a-c-project/51912672#51912672)

Calling C from C++ is pretty easy: each C function only has one possible non-mangled symbol, so no extra work is required.

main.cpp

```
#include <cassert>

#include "c.h"

int main() {
    assert(f() == 1);
}
```

c.h

```
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H

/* This ifdef allows the header to be used from both C and C++ 
 * because C does not know what this extern "C" thing is. */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
int f();
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

c.c

```
#include "c.h"

int f(void) { return 1; }
```

Run:

```
g++ -c -o main.o -std=c++98 main.cpp
gcc -c -o c.o -std=c89 c.c
g++ -o main.out main.o c.o
./main.out
```

Without `extern "C"` the link fails with:

```
main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `f()'
```

because `g++` expects to find a mangled `f`, which `gcc` did not produce.

[Example on GitHub](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/tree/bf5f48628d0b01ba6a3fcea6f1162b28539654c9/c-from-cpp).

**Minimal runnable C++ from C example**

Calling C++ from C is a bit harder: we have to manually create non-mangled versions of each function we want to expose.

Here we illustrate how to expose C++ function overloads to C.

main.c

```
#include <assert.h>

#include "cpp.h"

int main(void) {
    assert(f_int(1) == 2);
    assert(f_float(1.0) == 3);
    return 0;
}
```

cpp.h

```
#ifndef CPP_H
#define CPP_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
// C cannot see these overloaded prototypes, or else it would get confused.
int f(int i);
int f(float i);
extern "C" {
#endif
int f_int(int i);
int f_float(float i);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

cpp.cpp

```
#include "cpp.h"

int f(int i) {
    return i + 1;
}

int f(float i) {
    return i + 2;
}

int f_int(int i) {
    return f(i);
}

int f_float(float i) {
    return f(i);
}
```

Run:

```
gcc -c -o main.o -std=c89 -Wextra main.c
g++ -c -o cpp.o -std=c++98 cpp.cpp
g++ -o main.out main.o cpp.o
./main.out
```

Without `extern "C"` it fails with:

```
main.c:6: undefined reference to `f_int'
main.c:7: undefined reference to `f_float'
```

because `g++` generated mangled symbols which `gcc` cannot find.

[Example on GitHub](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/tree/bf5f48628d0b01ba6a3fcea6f1162b28539654c9/cpp-from-c).

**Where is the `extern "c"` when I include C headers from C++?**

- C++ versions of C headers like `cstdio` might be relying on `#pragma GCC system_header` which https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html mentions: "On some targets, such as RS/6000 AIX, GCC implicitly surrounds all system headers with an 'extern "C"' block when compiling as C++.", but I didn't fully confirm it.
- POSIX headers like `/usr/include/unistd.h` are covered at: [Do I need an extern "C" block to include standard POSIX C headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087438/do-i-need-an-extern-c-block-to-include-standard-posix-c-headers/8087539#8087539) via `__BEGIN_DECLS`, reproduced on Ubuntu 20.04. `__BEGIN_DECLS` is included via `#include <features.h>`.

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Best answer since you 1) explicitly mention that `extern "C" {` helps you call **unmangled C functions from within C++ programs**, as well as **unmangled C++ functions from within C programs**, which other answers don't make so obvious, *and* 2) because you show distinct examples of each. Thanks!

Comment: I'm wondering about C headers like unistd.h, sys/stat.h and sys.types.h. They don't seem to put the "'C'" after the "extern". Using them from C++ code still seems to be unproblematic. Is the reason, that these are pure headers without an implementation file?

Comment: @Paul they seem to enable extern C with the macro `__BEGIN_DECLS`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087438/do-i-need-an-extern-c-block-to-include-standard-c-headers/8087539#8087539 I observe what is mentioned in that answer on Ubuntu 20.04 for unistd.h. For `cstdio` however, it might be relying on the `#pragma GCC system_header`: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/System-Headers.html

Comment: Thanks! Weirdly that question didn't show up when I searched and now id did when I searched for that specific Macro... I guess it's good for it to be linked here. As __BEGIN_DECLS is defined in sys/cdefs.h but this isn't included in either of unistd.h, sys/stat.h and sys/types.h, I guess sys/cdefs.h is just included by the preprocessor by default?

Comment: @Paul no worries, we all live and die by the wims of the Google God. It gets included via `#include <features.h>`.

Comment: Alright. I guess I've seen enough of the POSIX/system headers for a while...

Answer (score 229):

In every C++ program, all non-static functions are represented in the binary file as symbols. These symbols are special text strings that uniquely identify a function in the program.

In C, the symbol name is the same as the function name. This is possible because in C no two non-static functions can have the same name.

Because C++ allows overloading and has many features that C does not — like classes, member functions, exception specifications - it is not possible to simply use the function name as the symbol name. To solve that, C++ uses so-called name mangling, which transforms the function name and all the necessary information (like the number and size of the arguments) into some weird-looking string processed only by the compiler and linker.

So if you specify a function to be extern C, the compiler doesn't performs name mangling with it and it can be directly 
accessed using its symbol name as the function name.

This comes handy while using `dlsym()` and `dlopen()` for calling such functions.

Comment: what do you mean by handy? is symbol name = function name would make symbol name passed to dlsym known, or other thing?

Comment: @Error: yes. It's essentially impossible in the general case to dlopen() a C++ shared library given only a header file and pick the right function to load. (On x86, there's a published name-mangling specification in the form of the Itanium ABI that all x86 compilers I know of use to mangle C++ function names, but nothing in the language requires this.)

Answer (score 99):

### C++ mangles function names to create an object-oriented language from a procedural language

Most programming languages aren't built on-top of existing programming languages. C++ is built on-top of C, and furthermore it's an object-oriented programming language built from a procedural programming language, and for that reason there are C++ expressions like `extern "C"` which provide backwards compatibility with C.

Let's look at the following example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
    
// Two functions are defined with the same name
//   but have different parameters

void printMe(int a) {
  printf("int: %i\n", a);
}

void printMe(char a) {
  printf("char: %c\n", a);
}
    
int main() {
  printMe('a');
  printMe(1);
  return 0;
}
```

A C compiler will not compile the above example, because the same function `printMe` is defined twice (even though they have different parameters `int a` vs `char a`).

> gcc -o printMe printMe.c && ./printMe;
> *1 error. PrintMe is defined more than once.*

However, a C++ compiler will compile the above example. It does not care that `printMe` is defined twice.

> g++ -o printMe printMe.c && ./printMe;

This is because a C++ compiler implicitly renames ([mangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)) functions based on their parameters. The language was designed to be object-oriented - to create different classes with methods (functions) of the same name, and to override methods names ([method overriding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding)) based on different parameters.

### What `extern "C"` says is "don't mangle C function names"

Even though C++ was built on C, mangling can cause a mess for C code. For example, imagine we have a legacy C file named "parent.c" that `include`s function names from different header files, "parent.h", "child.h", etc. If we run "parent.c" through a C++ compiler, that will mangle function names in that file, and they will no longer match the function names specified in the header files. So the function names in the "parent.h" and "child.h" header files would need to be mangled as well. This might be okay for a few files, but if the C program is complex, mangling could be slow and cause broken code, so it might be convenient to provide a keyword which tells the C++ compiler not to mangle function names.

The `extern "C"` keyword tells a C++ compiler not to mangle (rename) C function names.

For example:

`extern "C" void printMe(int a);`

Comment: can we don't use of `extern "C"` if we have just a `dll` file? I mean if we have not a header file and just have a source file (just implementations) and use of its function via function pointer. in this state, we just used of functions (regardless of its name).

Answer (score 34):

Not any C-header can be made compatible with C++ by merely wrapping in extern "C". When identifiers in a C-header conflict with C++ keywords the C++ compiler will complain about this.

For example, I have seen the following code fail in a g++ :

```
extern "C" {
struct method {
    int virtual;
};
}
```

Kinda makes sense, but is something to keep in mind when porting C-code to C++.

Comment: `extern "C"` means to use C linkage, as described by other answers. It doesn't mean to "compile the contents as C" or anything. `int virtual;` is invalid in C++ and specifying different linkage doesn't change that.

Comment: ... or mode generally, any code containing syntax error will not compile.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz naturally, though using "virtual" as an identifier in C is not a syntax error. I just wanted to point that you cannot automatically use *any* C header in C++ by putting extern "C" around it.

Comment: I just ran into a different compatibility issue. The C header used the struct prefix on some typedefs of structs. It compiled without errors or warnings on `-Wextra` with gcc and clang, but failed with g++ and clang++ because struct is only allowed on the original identifier, not a typedef of it. I had to modify the header to make it C++ compatible beyond just the `extern "C" {...}` wrapper and now it compiles on both C and C++ versions.

Answer (score 32):

It changes the linkage of a function in such a way that the function is callable from C. In practice that means that the function name is not [mangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling).

Comment: Mangled is the term generally used... Don't believe I've ever seen 'decorated' used with this meaning.

Comment: Microsoft (at least partially) uses [decorated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names?view=vs-2019) rather than mangled in their documentation. they even name their tool to undecorate (aka un-mangle) a name `undname`.

Answer (score 27):

It informs the C++ compiler to look up the names of those functions in a C-style when linking, because the names of functions compiled in C and C++ are different during the linking stage.

Answer (score 12):

`extern "C"` is meant to be recognized by a C++ compiler and to notify the compiler that the noted function is (or will be) compiled in C style, so that while linking, it links to the correct version of the function from C.

Answer (score 7):

`extern "C"` is a linkage specification which is used to **call C functions** in the **Cpp source files**. We can **call C functions, write Variables, & include headers**. Function is declared in extern entity & it is defined outside. Syntax is

**Type 1:**

```
extern "language" function-prototype
```

**Type 2:**

```
extern "language"
{
     function-prototype
};
```

**eg:**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C"
{
     #include<stdio.h>    // Include C Header
     int n;               // Declare a Variable
     void func(int,int);  // Declare a function (function prototype)
}

int main()
{
    func(int a, int b);   // Calling function . . .
    return 0;
}

// Function definition . . .
void func(int m, int n)
{
    //
    //
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I used 'extern "C"' before for dll(dynamic link library) files to make etc. main() function "exportable" so it can be used later in another executable from dll.
Maybe an example of where I used to use it can be useful.

DLL

```
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

#define DLL extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
//I defined DLL for dllexport function
DLL main ()
{
    MessageBox(NULL,"Hi from DLL","DLL",MB_OK);
}
```

EXE

```
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

typedef LPVOID (WINAPI*Function)();//make a placeholder for function from dll
Function mainDLLFunc;//make a variable for function placeholder

int main()
{
    char winDir[MAX_PATH];//will hold path of above dll
    GetCurrentDirectory(sizeof(winDir),winDir);//dll is in same dir as exe
    strcat(winDir,"\\exmple.dll");//concentrate dll name with path
    HINSTANCE DLL = LoadLibrary(winDir);//load example dll
    if(DLL==NULL)
    {
        FreeLibrary((HMODULE)DLL);//if load fails exit
        return 0;
    }
    mainDLLFunc=(Function)GetProcAddress((HMODULE)DLL, "main");
    //defined variable is used to assign a function from dll
    //GetProcAddress is used to locate function with pre defined extern name "DLL"
    //and matcing function name
    if(mainDLLFunc==NULL)
    {
        FreeLibrary((HMODULE)DLL);//if it fails exit
        return 0;
    }
    mainDLLFunc();//run exported function 
    FreeLibrary((HMODULE)DLL);
}
```

Comment: Bogus. `extern "C"` and `__declspec(dllexport)` are unrelated. The former controls symbol decoration, the latter is responsible for creating an export entry. You can export a symbol using C++ name decoration just as well. Besides completely missing the point of this question, there are other mistakes in the code sample as well. For one, `main` exported from your DLL doesn't declare a return value. Or calling convention, for that matter. When importing, you attribute a random calling convention (`WINAPI`), and use the wrong symbol for 32-bit builds (should be `_main` or `_main@0`). Sorry, -1.

Comment: Actualy that is just an working example where I used it before to export function, and it should be used just to get idea how it can be used. I didn't said it is necessary to use it this way. Also, DLL main () declared in dll is of type DLL which is -> (extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)) type not int or string, defined above and it does not return anything like void, I named it "main", but it can be named whatever and it should be not confused with "main" of type int in executable itself. However this compiles and works great with many other functions in dll with parameters and return also.

Comment: That only repeated, that you don't know, what you are doing, but doing it this way appears to work for you, for some undisclosed list of target platforms. You didn't address the issues I raised in my previous comment. This is still a down-vote, due to being wildly wrong (there's more, that didn't fit in a single comment).

Comment: I didn't said anywhere that I'm know what I am doing,I just said that I used extern "C" before in this way. Yes, it is works for me on windows only cause I tried it on that platform only,you can see "#include <windows.h>".WINAPI is just a macro that evaluates to stdcall to prevent corrupting the stack where caller and callee need to agree on a calling convention i learned that here too and it is used in placeholder for exported function "typedef LPVOID (WINAPI*Function)();" to prevent stack corruption on run. Maybe you are right but I actualy don't care at all about your down-vote,thrust me ;)

Comment: Posting an answer on Stack Overflow kind of implies, that you know what you are doing. This is expected. As for your attempt *"to prevent stack corruption on run"*: Your function signature specifies a return value of type `void*`, but your implementation doesn't return anything. That'll fly really well...

Comment: I implemented and posted an working example that I used before myself. If you implement something and it works, it kind of implies that you know what are you doing, so I decided to post. Actualy I specified, set type with typedef of exported function which is LPVOID: "typedef LPVOID (WINAPI*Function)();" and void* and LPVOID is the same where LPVOID is windows api for void* so you can use void* to point any type. So this means when you implement functions inside dll it is an undefined type until you put it inside a predefined placeholder where you need to specify type to match function in exe.

Comment: If you implement something, that **appears** to work, by pure luck, then you clearly do **not** know what you are doing (your *"working"* sample falls into that category). It's undefined behavior, and appearing to work is a valid form of undefined behavior. It's still undefined. I would highly appreciate it, if you exercised more diligence in the future. Part of that could be deleting this proposed answer.

Comment: By pure luck? You are trolling me man whole time, so this conversation is over.

Comment: You are reinterpreting a function that doesn't return anything as a function that returns a pointer. It is pure luck, that x86 is very forgiving with respect to mismatching function signatures, and in particular return values of integral type. Your code works by coincidence only. If you disagree, you need to explain, why your code works reliably.

Comment: This answer is completely unrelated to OP's question.`extern "C"` does not make a function exportable. That's simply nonsense.

Comment: Very good example of the topic discussed. Using this I have exported a VC++ function, then called it from C#, using https://stackoverflow.com/a/23623244/984471

Answer (score 4):

This answer is for the impatient/ have deadlines to meet to, only a part/simple explanation is below:

- in C++, you can have same name in class via overloading (for example, since they are all same name can't be exported as-is from dll, etc.) solution to these problems is they are converted to different strings (called symbols), symbols accounts the name of function, also the arguments, so each of these functions even with same name, can be uniquely identified (also called, name mangling)
- in C, you don't have overloading, the function name is unique (so, a separate string for identifying the a function name uniquely is not required, so symbol is function name itself)

So
in C++, with name mangling uniquely identities each function
in C, even without name mangling uniquely identities each function

To change the behaviour of C++, that is, to specify that name mangling *should not* happen for a particular function, you can use *extern "C"* before the function name, for whatever reason, like exporting a function with a specific name from a dll, for use by its clients.

Read other answers, for more detailed/more correct answers.

Answer (score 4):

A function void f() compiled by a C compiler and a function with the same name void f() compiled by a C++ compiler are not the same function. If you wrote that function in C, and then you tried to call it from C++, then the linker would look for the C++ function and not find the C function.

extern "C" tells the C++ compiler that you have a function which was compiled by the C compiler. Once you tell it that it was compiled by the C compiler, the C++ compiler will know how to call it correctly.

It also allows the C++ compiler to compile a C++ function in such a way that the C compiler can call it. That function would officially be a C function, but since it is compiled by the C++ compiler, it can use all the C++ features and has all the C++ keywords.

Comment: The C++ compiler can compile an `extern "C"` function — and (subject to some constraints) it will be callable by code compiled by a C compiler.

Answer (score 2):

### This is a demonstration with sample code.

This code clearly wouldn't compile in C because of two functions share same name, but can compile in C++, which allows overloading of functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char* get_message2(void); 
int get_message2(char*); 

int main() {
   char test[] = "BBBBBBB";
   get_message2(test);
   return 0;
}

const char* get_message2() {
    char test[] = "AAAAAAA";
    return "message2";
};

int get_message2(char* arg) {
    char test[] = "CCCCCCC";
   return 0;
}
```

In C++ function names are not unique symbol identifiers, and C++ compiler adds "prefixes" and "suffixes" to symbol name based on function prototype:

```
drazen@HP-ProBook-640G1:~/proba$ readelf  -a proba | grep message
    34: 0000000000001199    70 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 _Z12get_message2v
    36: 00000000000011df    72 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 _Z12get_message2Pc
```

But if we want for our function have a C linkage, we must add `extern "C"` modifier

```
const char* get_message2(void); 
extern "C" {
   int get_message2(char*); 
}
```

Now our `int get_message2(char*);` function has an old C linkage:

```
drazen@HP-ProBook-640G1:~/proba$ readelf  -a proba | grep message
    32: 00000000000011df    72 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 get_message2
    35: 0000000000001199    70 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 _Z12get_message2v
```

Comment: I like the visualization in this answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When mixing C and C++ (i.e., a. calling C function from C++; and b. calling C++ function from C), the C++ name mangling causes linking problems. Technically speaking, this issue happens only when the callee functions have been already compiled into binary (most likely, a *.a library file) using the corresponding compiler.

So we need to use extern "C" to disable the name mangling in C++.

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting, that neither Visual Studio nor dumpbin occur in this thread (until now). So I want to add some info about this as well.
(*If it makes sense, we could merge this into any of the above answers as well. I'm not sure about the SO philosophy here.*)

---

When compiling **with Visual Studio** compiler, each `extern "C"` symbol is preceded with **a leading underscore**.
example: compiling

```
extern "C"
void cf () {}

void cppf () {}
```

and running `dumpbin /symbols` on the resulting object, the symbols looks as following:

```
01A 00000000 SECT7  notype ()    External     | _cf
01B 00000000 SECT5  notype ()    External     | ?cppf@@YAXXZ (void __cdecl cppf(void))
```

Same for variables.

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
  int b;
}
CppStruct;

extern "C" {
  typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
  }
  CStruct;
  CStruct cCStruct;
  CppStruct cCppStruct;
}
CStruct cppCStruct;
CppStruct cppCppStruct;
```

`dumpbin /symbols`

```
009 00000000 SECT3  notype       External     | _cCStruct
00A 0000000C SECT3  notype       External     | _cCppStruct
00B 00000014 SECT3  notype       External     | ?cppCStruct@@3UCStruct@@A (struct CStruct cppCStruct)
00C 00000020 SECT3  notype       External     | ?cppCppStruct@@3UCppStruct@@A (struct CppStruct cppCppStruct)
```

side note: For C++ symbols, `dumpbin` also shows you the unmangled symbol name in parentheses.
side note 2: As you can see, `extern "C"` does not affect type definitions.

---

Look out! If a **variable** is **declared** somewhere **before without** `extern "C"` (e.g. in a header file), then it will be compiled with C++ linkage without further notice:

```
extern CppStruct ifcStruct;
extern int       ifcVar;
/* ... */

extern "C"
{
CppStruct ifcStruct;
int       ifcVar = 0;
}
```

`dumpbin /symbols`

```
00C 00000000 SECT4  notype       External     | ?ifcStruct@@3UCppStruct@@A (struct CppStruct ifcStruct)
00D 00000008 SECT4  notype       External     | ?ifcVar@@3HA (int ifcVar)
```

However, when a **function** is **declared** somewhere **before without** `extern "C"`, then the (Microsoft) compiler gives a distinct error message:

```
test.cpp(20): error C2732: linkage specification contradicts earlier specification for 'ifcf'
test.cpp(20): note: see declaration of 'ifcf'
```

(The reasons for this difference are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76437843/16049096).)

---

As far as I know, `extern "C"` also **tells the compiler to use C calling conventions**.
see also [Exporting C++ classes from a DLL - Eli Bendersky's website](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/16/exporting-c-classes-from-a-dll) (*Google still finds it, but the site seems dead*):

> `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) IKlass* __cdecl create_klass()`
> Let's see what each part means, in order:
>
> - `extern "C"` - tells the C++ compiler that the linker should use the C calling convention and name mangling for this function. The name itself is exported from the DLL unmangled (`create_klass`)
> - `__declspec(dllexport)` - tells the linker to export the `create_klass` symbol from the DLL. Alternatively, the name `create_klass` can be placed in a .def file given to the linker.
> - `__cdecl` - repeats that the C calling convention (opposite of `__stdcall` calling convention) is to be used. It's not strictly necessary here, but I include it for completeness (in the typedef for `iklass_factory` in the application code as well).

see also this [FAQ: How to mix C and C++](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Without conflicting with other good answers, I will add a bit of my example.

What exactly **C++ Compiler** does: it mangles the names in the compilation process, hence we require telling the compiler to **treat** `C` implementation specially.

When we are making C++ classes and adding `extern "C"`, we're telling our C++ compiler that we are using C calling convention.

**Reason (we are calling C implementation from C++):**  either we want to call C function from C++ or calling C++ function from C (C++ classes ... etc do not work in C).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
If you decide to answer an older question that has well established and
correct answers, adding a new answer late in the day may not get you any
credit.
If you have some distinctive new information, or you're convinced the
other answers are all wrong, by all means add a new answer, but 'yet
another answer' giving the same basic information a long time after the
question was asked usually won't earn you much credit.
Frankly, I don't think there's anything new in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

gcc seems to support name mangling as well recently. even inside `extern "c"`, if you use class or overloading, it will automatically mangle.

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C"{


struct myint{
    int i;
};

struct myint2
{
    int a;
    myint2(int a): a(a) {};
    operator myint() const {return myint{a};}
};

}

void f1(myint i){
    printf("%d", i.i);
}

int main(){
    myint2 a(1);
    f1(a);
}
```

I even used many cpp feature. but the code compiles and runs ok. if you `nm`, you can see `main` is not mangled, but myint is.